# Filter Instances based on tag name and print specific tag value in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, amazon-ec2

I wanted to filter my instances based on tag value. That is completed and i get multiple tag key and values for each instances.

Code:

```
client = boto3.client("ec2")
response = client.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'tag:Name',
            'Values': [
                'myapp-*'
            ]
        },
        {
            'Name': 'instance-state-name',
            'Values': [
                'running',
            ]
        }
    ]
)['Reservations']

for ec2_reservation in response:
    for ec2_instance in ec2_reservation["Instances"]:
       print(ec2_instance)
```

Response: (I removed all other fields intentionally and pasted only tags section below)

```
'Tags': [{'Key': 'Patch group', 'Value': 'Amazon-Linux'},
          {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'myapp-mgmt-1'},
          {'Key': 'environment', 'Value': 'devl'},
          {'Key': 'ssm-managed', 'Value': 'true'},

'Tags': [{'Key': 'Patch group', 'Value': 'Amazon-Linux'},
          {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'myapp-web-1'},
          {'Key': 'environment', 'Value': 'devl'},
          {'Key': 'ssm-managed', 'Value': 'true'},
```

Now while tried to print value of key-name i am not able to make it. Below is what i tried. Can you please help me sort this out. May be duplicated but was not able to find appropriate reference from other posts.

```
print(ec2_instance["Tags"][0][{'Name':'tag-key', 'Values':['Name']}])

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

I am expecting an output as:

```
'myapp-mgmt-1'
'myapp-web-1'
```

Comment: I am not getting what do you want..can you please post a sample output

Comment: I have edited inline. I am expecting an output of all Values where Key is "Name"

Comment: is `ec2_instance`  dict of dict ?

Comment: Yes its a dict @RahulAgarwal

Comment: Actually i was looking to grep {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': '----'} this line out of all the tags with the filter applied on Value only using python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I have it figured out. Here  is the complete code for your reference:

Note: Using boto3.resource I had to loop between instances to get their tag names.

```
client = boto3.client("ec2")
resource = boto3.resource("ec2")

response = client.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'tag:Name',
            'Values': [
                'myapp-*'
            ]
        },
        {
            'Name': 'instance-state-name',
            'Values': [
                'running',
            ]
        }
    ]
)['Reservations']

instanceList = []
for reservation in response:
    ec2_instances = reservation["Instances"]
    for instance in ec2_instances:
        InstanceId = (instance['InstanceId'])
        #InstanceState = (instance['State']['Name'])
        #InstanceLaunchTime = (instance['LaunchTime'])

        ec2instance = resource.Instance(InstanceId)
        InstanceName = []
        for tags in ec2instance.tags:
            if tags["Key"] == 'Name':
                InstanceName = tags['Value']

        fInstance = (InstanceName, InstanceId)
        InstanceDetails = (",".join(fInstance))
        instanceList.append(fInstance)

print(json.dumps(instanceList, indent=4))
```

As of now this works for me. Please let me know if you have any better way.